# android, recording audio with the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

i just new in the android world.

Basically i just want to record the users voice.
I have downloaded some samples and i have not been able to test them using the emulator.
Sine it's possible to enable "audio recording support" when creating a new Android Virtual Device, i'm just guessing what's wrong here.

questions:
is it possible to use the emulator for audio recording? how?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Media Recorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) can be used to record video and audio. However it mentions that currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator. If your samples are using this class, it seems it will not work on the emulator.

Also, it would be a good idea to post links to the samples you mentioned.

Comment: +1 nice answer.... I also had similar problem. Than I tried AudioRecord... is AudioRecord works on emulator ?